# how can i get two dimensional array in this format?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I got an array in this format.

```
   Date            Employee               Notes
   2013-03-08        ABC                 Notes of ABC on 08-03-2013
   2013-03-08        PQR                 Notes of PQR on 08-03-2013
   2013-03-08        XYZ                 Notes of XYZ on 08-03-2013
   2013-03-09        ABC                 Notes of ABC on 09-03-2013
   2013-03-09        PQR                 Notes of PQR on 09-03-2013
   2013-03-09        XYZ                 Notes of XYZ on 09-03-2013
```

And i want the result array in this format

```
 Date            Employee               Notes
 2013-03-08        ABC                 Notes of ABC on 08-03-2013
                   PQR                 Notes of PQR on 08-03-2013
                   XYZ                 Notes of XYZ on 08-03-2013
 2013-03-09        ABC                 Notes of ABC on 09-03-2013
                   PQR                 Notes of PQR on 09-03-2013
                   XYZ                 Notes of XYZ on 09-03-2013
```

So how can i write my php code to get result like this ??
This is a two dimensional array and i have used foreach loop to display like this.

Can anybody please help me ?

Comment: what did you try in PHP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
$entries = array(
    array("Date" => "2013-03-08", "Employee" => "ABC", "Notes" => "Notes of ABC on 08-03-2013"),
    array("Date" => "2013-03-08", "Employee" => "PQR", "Notes" => "Notes of PQR on 08-03-2013"),
    array("Date" => "2013-03-08", "Employee" => "XYZ", "Notes" => "Notes of XYZ on 08-03-2013"),
    array("Date" => "2013-03-09", "Employee" => "ABC", "Notes" => "Notes of ABC on 09-03-2013"),
    array("Date" => "2013-03-09", "Employee" => "PQR", "Notes" => "Notes of PQR on 09-03-2013"),
    array("Date" => "2013-03-09", "Employee" => "XYZ", "Notes" => "Notes of XYZ on 09-03-2013")
);

$y = array();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $date = $entry["Date"];
    if (!isset($y[$date])) $y[$date] = array();
    unset($entry["Date"]);
    $y[$date][] = $entry;
}

print_r($y);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Steven Moseley. My problem is solved by your solution. :)

Comment: hi Steven. Can you please help me in do it for two parameters ? Like right now we have done it with only dates but i want to do it with eventwise and then datewise. Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to iterate on the initial array, and store in a var the current date.
while the next date is not changing, you store the sub data in the same sub entry.

Assuming you have

```
$initial = array(
    array('2013-03-08','ABC','Notes of ABC on 08-03-2013'),
    array('2013-03-08','PQR','Notes of PQR on 08-03-2013'),
    array('2013-03-08','XYZ','Notes of XYZ on 08-03-2013'),
    array('2013-03-09','ABC','Notes of ABC on 09-03-2013'),
    array('2013-03-09','PQR','Notes of PQR on 09-03-2013'),
    array('2013-03-09','XYZ','Notes of XYZ on 09-03-2013')
)
```

You can make your new array like

```
$final = array();
$currentDate = false;
foreach($initial as $index => $subArray)
{
    if ($currentDate === false || $currentDate != $subArray[0])
    {
        $currentDate = $subArray[0];
        $final[$currentDate] = array();
    }

    $final[$currentDate][] = array($subArray[1], $subArray[2]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks user1073122 for your help.